# Property of diameter of a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a compact metric space. Take $x \in M$. Then, since $M$ is compact, there is a $y \in M$ such that $d(x,y)=\sup_{w \in M}d(x,w)$. Analogously, there is a $z \in M$ such that $d(y,z)=\sup_{w \in M}d(y,w)$.

Does it follow that $d(y,z)$ is equal to $M$'s diameter, that is, $\sup_{\xi \in M, \eta \in M}d(\xi, \eta)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider the four points $(0, \pm 3)$, $(0, 0)$, and $(4, 0)$. Because the set of these points is finite, it is a compact space (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the normal metric).

Let $x = (0, 0)$. Then the $y$ which is furthest from $x$ is $(4, 0)$. A $z$ which is furthest from $y$ is $(0, 3)$. The distance between $y$ and $z$ is 5.

However, the diameter of the space is 6.